# AODV routing accidentally gives two nodes the same IP address

Tags: routing, wireless, ad-hoc-wireless

I am learning AODV and if this routing accidentally gives same IP address to two nodes, then how do I send data to this IP address?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Routing protocols, including AODV, do not assign IP addresses.  That is handled by other means (DHCP for example).

Two hosts with the same IP address is an error condition, so that should not happen under normal circumstances.